# Read statement in fortran

Tags: io, fortran

I am trying to understand a small read function in my program I am trying to decipher.The code is below

```
 READ (LREST, END=350, ERR=350) ICHR

      IF (ICHR .EQ. ICKLNK) THEN
        DO L = 1, 4
          READ (LREST, END=350, ERR=350)
        ENDDO
```

So basically LREST is some kind of an argument provided for this subroutine this function is in. However, I found that LREST is not defined anywhere(used grep to see where LREST is defined in my *.f files. So my questions is what is that LREST doing there in READ function. I thought the location LREST is at is where the unit is defined.

Second questions is that ICHR is a 16 character string variable define for this subroutine. However, the contents of ICHR have not been assigned. I have no idea what this READ function is trying to read from.

Going over to IF statement, ICKLNK is another 16 character string variable with a defined strings. Because ICHR is not defined, does that mean this if statement never gets entered in?

Finally, the do loop( or for loop) has variable L in it but it is not even being used for read function inside of the loop.

Im a beginning in fortran so I may just be lacking a very basic knowledge but if you know an answer to my question please let me know. Thanks!

Han

Comment: if `LREST` is an argument it may very well have some other name in the unit that *calls* the subroutine.  One thing you want to do here is hunt down the corresponding `open` statement  (expect it is unformatted sequential access)

Answer (score 1):

You are correct that LREST is specifying the unit number (or internal file if it is character). You seem to suggest that LREST is an argument in this subroutine or function, which means its value is passed in by whoever calls the function. Showing us only a small piece of the code makes it hard to provide further details.

Again, you say ICHR is an argument to the procedure, so it takes on the value of whatever was passed in by the call. ICLNK is probably similar, but you didn't show all the code.

The DO (not for) loop is using L just as a counter; it doesn't need to be referenced inside the loop.

Comment: Even if `ichr` is a dummy argument, surely it'll have the value transferred into it by the `read` statement (except in certain cases)?

Comment: That is correct.The code appears to be reading a single value using an unformatted read statement and then comparing it to ICKLNK. If they are the same, then four more records are read from the unit identified by LREST.

Comment: The key is to find the original definition of `LREST`. If you have trouble finding a definition of `LREST` locally or as an argument, check any `INCLUDE` files used by the routine or (if F90 or later) check imports from modules (*i.e.* `use some_module`).

Comment: I went all the way up to the main function. So the small lines above is embeded in a subroutine called fldriv which gets called by another subroutine sphedfb which is called by the main.f. Somehow this variable LREST just appears out of nowhere in subroutine sphedfb even though it is not defined in main

Comment: CALL SPHDIFB (NMAX, LIN, LOUT, LINKCK, LINKTP, LRIN, LROUT,                
     1             LRCRVR, LENLWK, LWORK, LENIWK, IWORK, LENRWK,                
     2             RWORK, LENCWK, CWORK, LRATE, NMXROW, NMXCOL, NORD,
     3             LH2O, LCO2, LCO)

Comment: SUBROUTINE SPHDIFB (NMAX, LIN, LOUT, LINKCK, LINKMC, LREST, LSAVE,
     1                   LRCRVR, LENLWK, L, LENIWK, I, LENRWK, R,
     2                   LENCWK, C, LRATE, NMXROW, NMXCOL, NORD, LH2O,
     3                   LCO2, LCO)

Comment: This is how subroutine sphdfb is defined. You can see that LREST just appears out of nowhere. LREST is not defined anywhere either in main or sphdfb subroutine.

Comment: NVM I think I figured it out It seems like LRIN in main is LREST in sphdfb and LROUT is LSAVE